# The springMVC failed to instantiate the ThymeleafView

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

This is a springMVC program on tomcat using Thymeleaf,idea,maven,the tomcat can run normally,the program is able to enter a Controller, but tomcat will return a 500 web once the Controller return a html file of Thymeleaf, it seems that springMVC failed to instantiate the ThymeleafView,I don't know why it happens, here is my springMVC.xml web.xml and error report

springMVC.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="helloworld.Controller"></context:component-scan>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="order" value="1"/>
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="templateEngine">
            <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine">
                <property name="templateResolver">
                    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring5.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
                        <!-- 视图前缀 -->
                        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/templates/"/>
                        <!-- 视图后缀 -->
                        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
                        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML"/>
                        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:springMVC.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

error report

```
类型 异常报告

消息 Request processing failed: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView]: Unresolvable class definition

描述 服务器遇到一个意外的情况，阻止它完成请求。

例外情况

jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView]: Unresolvable class definition
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1019)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
根本原因。

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView]: Unresolvable class definition
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:150)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver.loadView(ThymeleafViewResolver.java:837)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver.createView(ThymeleafViewResolver.java:796)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:184)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1455)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1390)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1158)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1097)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
根本原因。

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletException
    java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver.loadView(ThymeleafViewResolver.java:837)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver.createView(ThymeleafViewResolver.java:796)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:184)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1455)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1390)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1158)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1097)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
根本原因。

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletException
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1449)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1257)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3373)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3578)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2754)
    org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:141)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver.loadView(ThymeleafViewResolver.java:837)
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafViewResolver.createView(ThymeleafViewResolver.java:796)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractCachingViewResolver.resolveViewName(AbstractCachingViewResolver.java:184)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.resolveViewName(DispatcherServlet.java:1455)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1390)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1158)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1097)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:683)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:792)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

I tried to add the following dependency in maven according to the error report

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and the ServletDispather seems not able to be deployed because that the tomcat error report changed to 404

Comment: Which Spring Boot version (why a web.xml then?) Which sprig version and which Tomcat version. I suspect you are using Tomcat 10 with an older version of Sprig (5.x) and Thymeleaf (3.0) which are for Tomcat 9.

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum's comment which is exactly the reason for the problem, my tomcat version is 10, my springMVC version is 6, but I used Thymeleaf-spring5, the problem was solved after I changed it to Thymeleaf-spring6, I didn't consider the version before.

Comment: That was also an incompatible combination I didn't cover yet :).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks M.Deinum's comment which is exactly the reason for the problem, my tomcat version is 10, my springMVC version is 6, but I used Thymeleaf-spring5, the problem was solved after I changed it to Thymeleaf-spring6, I didn't consider the version before.